# How do I sum up the score of players that are in several columns in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe which is called `myData`.

```
library(dplyr)
myLines="
name1   name2   value
Simon   Simon   42
Simon   George  34
"
myData <- read.table(text=myLines, header=TRUE)
```

What code (preferably dplyr) do I have to apply to `myData` in order to get the following result?

```
  name   value
  Simon   118
  George  34
```

The answer needs to be applicable to examples, where I have many name-columns instead of just two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can obtain all name-value pairs with `gather` and then summarize:

```
library(tidyr)
myData %>%
    gather(var, name, - value) %>%
    group_by(name) %>%
    summarise(value = sum(value))

# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   name   value
#   <chr>  <int>
# 1 George    34
# 2 Simon    118
```

Comment: beat me to it :)